# AsyncIO When does the second await occur in this task?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I have a python script which makes http requests asynchronously, provided a lists of urls, and here is the example code.

```py
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import httpx
import asyncio

async def httpx_get(client, url):
    resp1 = await client.get(url, timeout=5, allow_redirects=True) 
    # ... other computation ...
    resp2 = await client.get(url, timeout=5, allow_redirects=True) # what happens during this second await?

async def fetch_pages(urls):
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(verify=False) as client:
        # create task for all URLs
        coros = []
        for url in urls:
            coros.append(asyncio.create_task(httpx_get(client, url)))

        # await all tasks
        for coro in asyncio.as_completed(coros):
            resp = await coro 

def main():
    urls = [ "https://google.com", "https://yahoo.com", "https://youtube.com" ] 
    asyncio.run(fetch_pages(urls))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I realized there is a lack of understanding on my part with when asyncio would handle the second await, `resp2 = await client.get(..`, in my `httpx_get` function.

Since `for coro in asyncio.as_completed(coros): resp = await coro` only resolves the first await, `resp1 = await client.get`, for each coroutine, when does the second await `resp2 = await client.get` get resolved?

is the second await/request performed and waited for all at once? or does something else happen? Any clarification would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `await` "pauses" there until the promise is resolved. For `async` functions, the promise is resolved when the function `return`s. In this case, it's the final, implied, `return undefined` that resolves the promise for `await coro`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...when asyncio would handle the second await, resp2 = await client.get(.., in my httpx_get function.

At the first await the eventloop will pause this task and go on to do other things, eventually checking if `client.get` has returned. If it has this task will continue executing till it encounters the second await `resp2  =await...` the eventloop handles this second `await` like the first - it suspends the task and goes on to do other things till it checks to see if the coroutine has returned.

---

Here is an example substituting a time delay for retrieving the url - hopefully it is analogous and will show how things might evolve for your process.

```
import asyncio,random,time

async def httpx_get(client, url):
    print(f'{time.time()} task:{client} resp1 will be called')
    resp1 = await asyncio.sleep(random.randrange(1,10))
    # ... other computation ...
    print(f'{time.time()} task:{client} resp1 returned')
    print(f'{time.time()} task:{client} executing')
    print(f'{time.time()} task:{client} executing')
    print(f'{time.time()} task:{client} executing')
    print(f'{time.time()} task:{client} executing')
    print(f'{time.time()} task:{client} resp2 will be called')
    resp2 = await asyncio.sleep(random.randrange(1,10))
    print(f'{time.time()}  task:{client} resp2 returned')
    return f'{time.time()} task:{client} finished - url'

async def fetch_pages(urls):
    # create task for all URLs
    coros = []
    for n,url in enumerate(urls):
        coros.append(asyncio.create_task(httpx_get(n, url)))

    # await all tasks
    for coro in asyncio.as_completed(coros):
        resp = await coro 
        print(f'{time.time()} {resp}')

def main():
    urls = [ "https://google.com", "https://yahoo.com", "https://youtube.com" ] 
    asyncio.run(fetch_pages(urls))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

Result from an execution:

```
1659744155.1480112 task:0 resp1 will be called and awaited
1659744155.1480112 task:1 resp1 will be called and awaited
1659744155.1480112 task:2 resp1 will be called and awaited
1659744161.152556 task:2 resp1 returned
1659744161.152556 task:2 executing
1659744161.152556 task:2 executing
1659744161.152556 task:2 executing
1659744161.154198 task:2 executing
1659744161.154198 task:2 resp2 will be called and awaited
1659744163.1660972 task:1 resp1 returned
1659744163.1660972 task:1 executing
1659744163.1660972 task:1 executing
1659744163.1660972 task:1 executing
1659744163.1660972 task:1 executing
1659744163.1675234 task:1 resp2 will be called and awaited
1659744164.1542242 task:0 resp1 returned
1659744164.1542242 task:0 executing
1659744164.1542242 task:0 executing
1659744164.1542242 task:0 executing
1659744164.155838 task:0 executing
1659744164.155838 task:0 resp2 will be called and awaited
1659744166.167943  task:2 resp2 returned
1659744166.167943 1659744166.167943 task:2 finished - https://youtube.com
1659744168.1679864  task:1 resp2 returned
1659744168.1685212 1659744168.1685212 task:1 finished - https://yahoo.com
1659744169.1565957  task:0 resp2 returned
1659744169.1565957 1659744169.1565957 task:0 finished - https://google.com
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, were my confusion lies is when the second await, `resp2 = await client.get(` actually gets resolved. 

From what I can tell `for coro in asyncio.as_completed(coros): resp = await coro`
resolves the first await in every co-routine but, when does the second await, `resp2 = await client.get(` get resolved?

Comment: `but, when does the second await ... get resolved?` - the next time the eventloop gets around to checking and it has returned. I've added an example substituting a time delay for retrieving the url - hopefully it is analogous and will show how things might evolve for your process.

Comment: ah ok I see thanks for the clarification, I think I see where my confusion is, it seems that every coroutine's first request is awaited during the first iteration of the `for coro in asyncio.as_completed(coros):` loop or in other words awaiting the coroutine will resolve both awaits in the function. For some reason the loop awaits all three coroutines instead of a single one in the first loop iteration, do you know why this is?

Comment: You might want to start by watching some pycon talks at pyvideo.org - [https://pyvideo.org/search.html?q=asyncio](https://pyvideo.org/search.html?q=asyncio).